# How to make an a href do its work when it's inside another class that triggers an event whenver clicked

Tags: javascript, html, web, href

The question above might not be clear enough, so I will give an example as well:

For example, I have the following html code:

```
<ul class="do-sth">
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Some text. <a href="http://www.google.com">Line 2.</a> Other text</li>
</ul>
```

The `do-sth` class triggers some even whenver it got clicked. So when I click `Line 2`, it will trigger that `do-sth` event and at the same time transferring to the href link. This is NOT what I want. What I would like to have is that whenever I click `Line 2`, the `do-sth` is not triggered. How to do that?

Comment: So you basically don't want the url to be clickable?

Comment: @mwilson, what I want is as follows: 1) when I click `Line 1` or `Some text` or `Other text`, the `do-sth` event is triggered; 2) when I click `Line 2`, the `do-sth` is not triggered and the web goes to www.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="do-sth">
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Some text. <a href="somewhere">Line2</a>. Other text</li>
</ul>

<script>
    // try using event.stopPropagation or event.cancelBubble = true for IE
    document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // do-sth won't be triggered
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hawk, I modified the code to the following as I am using jQuery: `$('body').on('click', 'a', function(event)
  {
   event.stopPropagation();
  });`

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is to remove the `onclick` event from the anchor tag, the below code will work:

```
    <ul class="do-sth">
        <li>Line 1</li>
        <li>Some text. <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return false">Line 2.</a> Other text</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I think this one will stop the href but triggers the do-sth, right?